# How do I change color of menu elements while scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change the **color of menu elements while scrolling** page for the following template. I followed some method but it's not dynamic.
How do I change it to dynamic?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

//scrolling animation

 $('.navigation a').on('click',function(){ 

  var target = $(this);
  var element = target.attr('href');
  
  $('.navigation a').removeClass('active');
  target.addClass('active');

  navHeight = $(".navigation").height();

     $("body, html").animate({ 
       scrollTop: $( element ).offset().top + navHeight - 120 
     }, 800);
 });

  //changing color of menu elements when scrolling

  $(window).scroll(function() {

   var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();

   if(scrollTop < 1000) {
    $(".navigation a").removeClass('active');
    $("a[title='About']").addClass('active');
   }
   else if(scrollTop > 1001 && scrollTop < 2000) {
    $(".navigation a").removeClass('active');
    $("a[title='Work']").addClass('active');
   }
   else if(scrollTop > 2001 && scrollTop < 3000) {
    $(".navigation a").removeClass('active');
    $("a[title='Clients']").addClass('active');
   }
   else if(scrollTop > 3001 && scrollTop < 4200) {
    $(".navigation a").removeClass('active');
    $("a[title='Blogs']").addClass('active');
   }
   else if(scrollTop > 4200 && scrollTop < 4600) {
    $(".navigation a").removeClass('active');
    $("a[title='Contact']").addClass('active');
   }
  });


});
```

```css
* {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

body {
 font-size: 16px;  
 background: #eee;
 padding-top: 90px;
 font-family: 'Roboto',Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

.navigation {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 padding: 0 10%;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 color: #fff;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background: #363636;
 text-align: center;
}
.navigation a {
 color: inherit;
 margin: 35px 5px;
 line-height: 150%; 
 padding: 0 5px 0 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}

.navigation a.active { color: yellow;}
.navigation a:first-child { border: 0; }
.box {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 font-size: 14vw;
 padding-top: 100px;
 text-align: center; 
 background: #4CD2DA;
}
.box:nth-child(2) { background: #59DAE2; }
.box:nth-child(3) { background: #4372A6; }
.box:nth-child(4) { background: #D8E0E3; }
.box:nth-child(5) { background: #4B565A; }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>ScrollSpy</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scrollspy.css">
</head>
<body>
 <nav class="navigation">
  <a class="active" href="#about" title="About">About</a>
  <a href="#work" title="Work">Work</a>
  <a href="#clients" title="Clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#blogs" title="Blogs">Blogs</a>
  <a href="#contact" title="Contact">Contact</a>
 </nav>
 
 <div id="container">
  <div id="about" class="box">
   About

  </div>
  <div id="work" class="box">
   Work 
  </div>
  <div id="clients" class="box">
   Clients
  </div>
  <div id="blogs" class="box">
   Blogs
  </div>
  <div id="contact" class="box">
   Contact
  </div>
 </div>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scrollspy.js"></script>
 

</body>
</html>
```

[copepen example here](https://codepen.io/bharathkumar_sriram/pen/XRQpRo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to calculate when the scroll reaches one of the boxes `.box` and then add class active to the corresponding menu item.

see snippet below or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abogvgsb/13/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //scrolling animation

  $('.navigation a').on('click', function() {

    var target = $(this);
    var element = target.attr('href');

    $('.navigation a').removeClass('active');
    target.addClass('active');

    navHeight = $(".navigation").height();

    $("body, html").animate({
      scrollTop: $(element).offset().top + navHeight - 120
    }, 800);
  });

  //changing color of menu elements when scrolling

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();

    $(".box").each(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      var height = $(this).outerHeight();
      var oTop = $(this).offset().top - 120;
      if (scrollTop > oTop && scrollTop < oTop + height) {
        $(".navigation a[href='#" + id + "']").addClass("active");

      } else {
        $(".navigation a[href='#" + id + "']").removeClass("active");
      }
    });


  });


});
```

```css
* {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #eee;
  padding-top: 90px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.navigation {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 10%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #363636;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation a {
  color: inherit;
  margin: 35px 5px;
  line-height: 150%;
  padding: 0 5px 0 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}

.navigation a.active {
  color: yellow;
}

.navigation a:first-child {
  border: 0;
}

.box {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 14vw;
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4CD2DA;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background: #59DAE2;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  background: #4372A6;
}

.box:nth-child(4) {
  background: #D8E0E3;
}

.box:nth-child(5) {
  background: #4B565A;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation">
  <a class="active" href="#about" title="About">About</a>
  <a href="#work" title="Work">Work</a>
  <a href="#clients" title="Clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#blogs" title="Blogs">Blogs</a>
  <a href="#contact" title="Contact">Contact</a>
</nav>

<div id="container">
  <div id="about" class="box">
    About

  </div>
  <div id="work" class="box">
    Work
  </div>
  <div id="clients" class="box">
    Clients
  </div>
  <div id="blogs" class="box">
    Blogs
  </div>
  <div id="contact" class="box">
    Contact
  </div>
</div>
```